# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'render_context'

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, django-1.9, django-2.2

I have moved up from Django 1.9.7 to Django 2.2.

When I render my view, it ends up with the below error -

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'render_context'

View - 
@login_required
def query_store_admin(request):
   template_name = "query_store/query_store_overview.html"       ##
   print(template_name)
   return render(request, template_name)

Traceback - 

Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/query_store/query_store_admin

Django Version: 2.2.6
Python Version: 3.6.8

Traceback:

File "/home/pgp/Desktop/Env/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/pgp/Desktop/Env/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/pgp/Desktop/Env/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py" in inner
52.                 return func(*args, **kwds)

File "/home/pgp/Desktop/Env/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/pgp/Desktop/Clickwork/query_store/views.py" in query_store_admin
185.     return render(request, template_name)

File "/home/pgp/Desktop/Env/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/home/pgp/Desktop/Env/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/home/pgp/Desktop/Env/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
62.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/home/pgp/Desktop/Env/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
167.         with context.render_context.push_state(self):

Exception Type: AttributeError at /query_store/query_store_admin
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'render_context'
```

I tried a lot of things from web, but that didn't help. Could someone make me understand what actually needs to be done here.

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions or insights here...

Comment: Show your view. Why aren't you passing a context?

Comment: Daniel. I have added my view function above. For this, I don't think there's any context. This was actual working code in Django 1.9 but later when i moved to 2.2, this started giving issues.